# Memory Leaks Comet Server in PHP

Tags: php, python, comet, tornado, long-polling

Why would a `Comet` Server like `Tornado` be especially prone to memory leaks if written in `PHP`?

Are there genuine weaknesses particular to `PHP` for implementing a long polling framework/service like `Tornado`?

Thanks

Comment: Related: [Is it wise to use PHP for a daemon?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/646928)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gist of it is that PHP was originally written with the intent of having a brand new process for every request that you could just throw away once said request ended, at a time where things like Comet and long polling weren't really on the table.

As such there are quite a few areas - notably the garbage collector - where at its origin PHP just wasn't made for running during a long period of time, and it didn't care much because every http request got a brand new php instance.

It got clearly better in the recent years, but I still wouldn't use it for creating that sort of long-lifetime applications.

Comment: Thanks!..i see...but i assume it OK as the client in a comet arrangement? The connection is held for ~1 minute but this is much smaller than the overall time that the comet server has to be running for...

Comment: Yes it is very much ok in such a situation